# How to avoid repeating http requests angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, httprequest

Is there a way in Angular to avoid repeating http requests?
As you can see in the code above I'm making a call to retrieve the detailed info of a product. 
The fact is that this call is associated to a button...
I would to avoid repetitive calls.
If I have clicked on the detailed-product-button obviously I don't need to make a call again to my service....the proper way will be to load the info once and then show and hided; but I don't know how to manage this on Angular.
(also I don't want to load the detail product from the scrach for very product, I want to loaded only on user's clic demand, but once)

```
$scope.seeInfo= function(id){

    $http.get('/shop/getDetailInfo/'+id).
        success(function(data, status) {
            $scope.info = data.detailinfo;
            if (data.detailinfo>0) $scope.showDetails=true;
            else $scope.showDetails=false;
        });

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store every item that the user request in a factory and then check if the content is in the factory before do the ajax call.

```
   $scope.seeInfo= function(id){
        var detailinfo = someFactory.get(id); //get item data from factory if exist
        if (angular.isUndefined(detailinfo) || detailinfo === null) {
            $http.get('/shop/getDetailInfo/'+id).
                success(function(data, status) {
                    someFactory.set(id, data); //set ajax data to factory
                    $scope.info = data.detailinfo;
                    if (data.detailinfo>0) $scope.showDetails=true;
                    else $scope.showDetails=false;
                });
            }
        } else {
            $scope.info = detailinfo;
            if (detailinfo>0) $scope.showDetails=true;
            else $scope.showDetails=false;
        }
    };
```

As well as someone said you can use the $http cache but i don't know how really it works

**UPDATE**

A someFactory example:

```
.factory('someFactory', [function() {

    var storedItems = [];

    return {
        get: function(id) {
            return storedItems[id];
        },
        set: function(id, data) {
            storedItems[id] = data;
        }
    };

}]);
```

test the factory:

```
someFactory.set(12345, {"info":"Hello"});
someFactory.set(2, "World");

console.log(someFactory.get(12345).info); // returns Hello
console.log(someFactory.get(2)); //returns World
```

You can store strings, objects....

Hope it helps you

**UPDATE2** FULL EXAMPLE CODE

```
var someApp = angular.module("someApp", [])

.controller('someCtrl', ['someFactory', function(someFactory) {

  someFactory.set(12345, {"info":"Hello"});
  someFactory.set(2, "World");

  console.log(someFactory.get(12345).info); // returns Hello
  console.log(someFactory.get(2)); //returns World

}]).factory('someFactory', [function() {

    var storedItems = [];

    return {
        get: function(id) {
            return storedItems[id];
        },
        set: function(id, data) {
            storedItems[id] = data;
        }
    };

}]);
```

Comment: Your solution seems pretty cool, but can you provide me more info about how to declare the "someFactory" ? thanks again

Comment: you need to "attach" this factory to your controller in some way don't you? I'm getting an error but I think it's because I missed this part..sorry!

Comment: you need to inject it (someFactory) as a dependency of your controller like $scope or $http

Comment: @FrnndSgz see the last update with a full code example

Comment: Oooh! thanks for the full version.
By the way does the $cacheFactory -provided by Angular- a similar thing?
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory

Comment: hum.. i didn't know about `$cacheFactory` (i'm a fool) but looking the code it seems to do something similar with extra features (delete entry, delete all, not overwrite....). It really depends of what you need and if you want to implement more "features" to your factory. For example, you can call the $http.get directry from the factory instead from your controller and then return the result. If you don't need to separate your logic you can use `$cacheFactory` or if you want to do more things, you can use your own factory. There are some different ways to work.

Answer (score 5):

Angular $http has a cache functionality built in, might be all you need

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

```
$scope.seeInfo= function(id){

    $http.get('/shop/getDetailInfo/'+id, {cache: true}).
        success(function(data, status) {
            $scope.info = data.detailinfo;
            if (data.detailinfo>0) $scope.showDetails=true;
            else $scope.showDetails=false;
        });

};
```

**update**

I see you went for the "roll your own" solution instead, which generally is more bug prone than using what angular provides.

Here how to achieve the same:

```
// access the $http cache 
var httpCache = $cacheFactory('$http');
// retrieve an element from cache
var detailInfo = httpCache.get('/shop/getDetailInfo/' + id);
// delete a cache element
httpCache.remove('/shop/getDetailInfo/' + id);
```

Comment: Fantastic! this works perfectly, thanks a lot.
Now I'm wondering if my approach is correct, because I think is not very smarty to make a call every time you show hide elements..

Comment: I recommend you read John's Papa best practice (https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#data-services) if you want something that "feel" better

Answer (score 1):

Bind first call with scope variable.

```
$scope.wasCalled = false;
$scope.seeInfo= function(id){
    if ( $scope.wasCalled == false ) {
    $http.get('/shop/getDetailInfo/'+id).
        success(function(data, status) {
            $scope.info = data.detailinfo;
            $scope.wasCalled = true;
        });
    }
};
```

it's set on success so the server error code would be between 200 and 299. 
Then you can set **ng-show** in view basing on `$scope.wasCalled` variable.

---

Here is implementation taking into account different id calls.

```
$scope.callIds = [];
$scope.wasCalled = function(id){
for ( var k = 0 ; k < $scope.callIds.length ; k++ ) 
    if ( $scope.callIds[k] == id ) 
        return true;
return false;
};
$scope.addCalled = function(id){
    $scope.callIds.push(id);
};
$scope.seeInfo= function(id){
    if ( $scope.wasCalled(id) == false ) {
    $http.get('/shop/getDetailInfo/'+id).
        success(function(data, status) {
            $scope.info = data.detailinfo;
            $scope.addCalled(id);
        });
    }
};
```

Checking if specified id was called, if not, call with $http and add id to list.

Comment: What if you need to call it with a different id?